# UIPickerview and Core Data with relationship

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, uipickerview

I have two Entitys named Logbook(to-one-boats) and Boats(to-many-Logbook).
When i register a new log in Logbook, I have a UIPickerview that is filled with boats. Everything works when registering.
But if I open a already registered log, What is best practice to set selected boat in picker view from relationship? For now i compare boatname(string) and set the selected. But Im not feeling comfortable with it :)
Im programming in Swift

Comment: Not super sure I understand what you mean, but its usually better to compare indexes instead of string comparison. So you would compare the index of your uiviewpicker and some list with the same order.

Comment: yes, i know, I'm used to use indexes in fex sql. Im a newbe in programming Swift and using Xcode. But as far as i know, there are no indexes in Core Data, and uipickerview only takes one string of text for each selection. There are no other fields :)

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is basically having a way to identify a coredata entry based on a selection in `UIPickerView`.

When you fetch all your core-data entries you fetch them as a list, and then you fill your pickerview with a string value from the coredata entries.

What you should do is you should store those fetched coredata entries as a list of coredata entry objects in a field variable, and then populate your pickerview just as you do today. The two lists (coredata and pickerview data) should now have the same order (unless you for some reason changed them). This means you can easily identify the coredata entry based on the selected index from pickerview. Since you have a list of coredata entries, you can simply change whatever field you need and just update the entry directly. You dont need to lookup a entry based on a criteria, since you already have the entry ready to use.

If you for some reason need to change the order of the elements in the pickerview (say alphabetically) you either need to rearrange your coredata list as well, or just add the ordering as a predicate when you fetch the coredata entries in the first place.

Comment: I really appreciate your answering, and I see my question is a little bit confusing :)
Let me ask a little bit different. Lets say I'm using a SQL server with two tables, "Person" and "PostalCode". In "Person", i would have a field named "postalCodeID" and stored the id from "PostalCode" in that field based on what i picked in a dropdown box.
When viewing a already stored "Person", I could use the stored "postalCodeID"  against a value field in dropdownbox to set its initial selected value.
So my question is how to do this with Core Data a UIPickerview instead of a dropdownbox. :)

Comment: Indexes can change all the time, and I have not a problem with saving the relation. The problem is how to pre-select the picker view :)

Comment: Its better to use coredata's object relation mapping instead of passing around id's and having to lookup the different objects. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-21505

That being said, if you do this approach you would end up with an PostalCode object (instead of postalcodeid). But you would need to fetch all  rows from the PostalCode table, use the list as the datasource, and preselect the object you already have saved on your Person object.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, and I am using the Core Data relation mapping. What i wrote about id's was only an example for what I'm trying to accomplish taken from a relation based database point of view, which i know very well... :)
I still dont see how i will be able to preselect a UIPickerview wich only take strings.
I have an object with Person, and a object with all Postalcodes sorted ascending by codes. I fill the Pickerview with Postalcodes. I also have the stored object from to-one relation.
So how do i preselect UIPickerview...?

Comment: Ah, ok. You need to loop over the list items you set as the datasource for the uipickerview (all postalcodes). Match the selected postalcode (from personobject) with one of them, and extract the index. Using this index, you set the selected row as such:
https://goo.gl/w7RmG6

And to your original question, instead of comparing strings, you should compare the managedobjects with the `objectId` property. This is the preferred way of comparing managedObjects for equality.
https://goo.gl/fF3hSV